# Erro ao Gerar o Scaffold

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, expressões-lambda, scaffold

Fiz o scaffolding gerando o controller, e a Index está apresentando um erro no

> (f => f.Cargo)

com este erro:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a
>   delegate

a classe Funcionário Herda pessoas, e tem como relacionamento Cargo, já a classe Pessoa tem como relacionamento Tipo e PessoaEndereco
Abaixo está o Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var pessoas = (Funcionario)db.Pessoas.Include(f => f.PessoaEndereco).Include(f => f.Tipo).Include(f => f.Cargo);
    return View(pessoas.ToList());
}
```

Aqui as classes:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome")]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 2 e no máximo 150 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Celular")]
    public string Celular { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("WhatsApp")]
    public string Whatsapp { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "O E-mail deve ter no máximo 150 caracteres.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CPF")]
    [DisplayName("CPF")]
    [StringLength(14, MinimumLength = 14, ErrorMessage = "O CPF deve 14 caracteres.")]
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    //relacionamentos
    public int TipoPessoaID { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoPessoa Tipo { get; set; }

    public int PessoaEnderecoID { get; set; }
    public virtual PessoaEndereco PessoaEndereco { get; set; }
}


public class TipoPessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int TipoPessoaID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tipo: ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome do tipo de usuário")]
    [Remote("VerificaTipo", "TipoPessoa", ErrorMessage = "Esse TIPO já existe no sistema")]
    //[RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Favor informe um e-mail válido")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    //relacionamentos
    public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Usuarios { get; set; }

}


public class PessoaEndereco
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaEnderecoID { get; set; }

    //Relacionamentos
    public int PessoaID { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }
    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}


public class Funcionario:Pessoa
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o RG")]
    [DisplayName("RG")]
    public string RG { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o numero da CTPS")]
    [DisplayName("CTPS")]
    public string CTPS { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha data de nascimento")]
    [DisplayName("Data de Nascimento")]
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a data de admissão")]
    [DisplayName("Data de Admissão")]
    public DateTime DataAdmissao { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [DisplayName("Data de Demissão")]
    public DateTime DataDemissao { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Salário.")]
    [DisplayName("Salário")]
    public decimal Salario { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Confirmar E-mail")]
    [Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "E-mail e confirmação não são identicos.")]
    public string ConfirmaEmail { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "A senha deve ter no mínimo 5 e no máximo 25 caracteres.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a senha.")]
    [DisplayName("Senha")]
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Confirmar Senha")]
    [Compare("Senha", ErrorMessage = "Senha e confirmação não são identicos.")]
    public string ConfirmaSenha { get; set; }

    //Relacionamentos
    public int NiveAcessolID { get; set; }
    public virtual NivelAcesso NivelAcesso { get; set; }

    public int CargoID { get; set; }
    public virtual CargoFuncionario Cargo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Pedido> Pedidos { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solucionei meu problema incluindo o **.OfType< Funcionario>()**

```
var pessoas = db.Pessoas.OfType<Funcionario>().Include(f => f.PessoaEndereco).Include(f => f.Tipo).Include(f => f.Cargo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está esquecendo de importar as seguintes bibliotecas `System.Linq` e `System.Data.Entity`. Adicione o código abaixo na parte superior da sua classe:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
```

### Atualizado

Vale ressaltar que, caso queira, você pode passar uma string com o nome da propriedade que deseja dar o include. Por exemplo:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var pessoas = (Funcionario)db.Pessoas
                                 .Include("PessoaEndereco")
                                 .Include("Tipo")
                                 .Include("Cargo");

    return View(pessoas.ToList());
}
```

Mas recomendo dar os include's através de expressões lambdas, pois, desta forma, fica fácil mapear os pontos de impacto ao alterar determinada entidade.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, já achei a solução para meu problema, vou postar a resposta.

Comment: Beleza! Por nada. =D